# Vue.js + vue-resource + vue-router = Lexical declaration error?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, vue-resource

When trying to use Vue.js with vue-resource and vue-router a error is shown:

> ReferenceError: can't access lexical declaration `vm' before
>   initialization

As far a I tracked the error down it only appears when the page is loaded with an initial route, e.g. test.com/#/files (error) and test.com/ (no error). If all code of `requestDirectory()` is replaced by `next()` the error will not be shown. So it seems inherit to code structure. Any ideas?

```
const routerComponents = {
    home: {     template: '<p>Home ...</p>' },
    files: { template: '<p>Files</p>' }
};

function requestDirectory(to, from, next) {
    console.log("Loading files in ...");
    vm.$http.post('/api/dir', {dir: 'photos'}).then((res) => {
        console.log("done");
        next()
    }, (err) => {});
}

const router = new VueRouter({
    routes: [
        { path: '/', component: routerComponents.home },
        { path: '/files', component: routerComponents.files, beforeEnter: requestDirectory }
    ]
});

const vm = new Vue({
    data: {
        title: 'Home'
    },
    router: router
});

window.onload = function() {
    vm.$mount('#app');
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access `vm` or `this` in `beforeEnter` callback because at this point component's instance has not been created yet. Try to move your code to one of provided by component instance events such as `created`.

***UPDATED***

Just replace `vm.$http` with a global shortcut `Vue.http`

Found in a documentation [there](https://github.com/pagekit/vue-resource/blob/master/docs/http.md).

Comment: I read this, but this would mean one cannot use vue-router and vue-resource??

Comment: there are different types of components - router components is all about routing, as i understand it right. Anyway, would you try to access it globally via `Vue.http` instead of `vm.$http`?

Comment: `Vue.http` works, but it leads to a new error "next undefined".All in all I placed the HTTP request in the components `created` callback an it works.

Answer (score 1):

This is the difference between `var` and `const`/`let` in ES6.

ES6 will still hoist the `let`/`const` variable to the top of the block. However, using the variable before the `const`/`let` declaration will result in a ReferenceError. The variable is in a "temporal dead zone" from the start of the block until the declaration is processed.

For further information see, *ECMAScript® 2017 Language Specification* [13.3.1 Let and Const Declarations](http://ECMAScript%C2%AE%202017%20Language%20Specification)